# Opengl drawing a section of a texture stretched over a quad

Tags: opengl, textures, sprites, spritesheet

**Current Situation**

I have a spritesheet loaded in for a texture when drawing the specific portions of the sheet that I'd like to have on my quads I do some simple math to get their location on the sheet and normalize it.

My texture is setup like this:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

**The Problem**

Where I'm facing the problem is that because I'm using a "chunk" of the total texture I can't take advantage of using 1.0 for the mapping of values to `glTexCoordPointer` to cause the texture to stretch over the entire face.

*Looked Into*

I've looked for a `glTexParameterf` option for scaling options but I failed to find anything.

*Question*

Is it possible with my current methods to stretch the texture over the face of the quad without having to load a separate image for every "sprite" of the texture? Or am I just doing everything completely wrong?

Picture that hopefully sort of clarifies:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

**edit**
The problem was another issue all together:
Turns out it was another issue all together, I thought this didn't make sense cause it was mapping it to the vertices so it should stretch regardless and infact it does work right I was assigning the wrong the width and height values to the drawing routines calculations. And now I feel really stupid, thanks for the help Byte56. Sorry for taking up your time. The GL_CLAMP solution would be the correct answer if I hadn't made a huge fail.

Comment: How are you assigning the texture coordinates to the quad?

Comment: (x, y) of position in texture divided accordingly (x/width) (y/height) become x0 and y0. Then the same for with the width and height of that `chunk` added on become x1 and y1. Then `GLfloat texture_coords[] = {x0, y0, x1, y0, x1, y1, x0, y1};` using `glTexCoordPointer` obviously.

Comment: Try: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

Comment: Turns out it was another issue all together, I thought this didn't make sense cause it was mapping it to the vertices so it should stretch regardless and infact it does work right I was assigning the wrong the width and height values to the drawing routines calculations. And now I feel really stupid, thanks for the help Byte56. Sorry for taking up your time. The GL_CLAMP solution would be the correct answer if I hadn't made a huge fail.

Comment: Ah, well I was just making my comment into an answer. I guess it's moot then. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your assigning the textures to the vertices correctly. I don't see how you're getting the results you're getting with what you've shown us. But you may want to try this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
```